Movie where a group of people are stuck in the abandoned psychiatric institution they were tortured in as kids
I'm looking for a movie about group of accomplished adults that were lured by invitation to some kind of reunion. Upon driving there they can't come back and keep driving in circles, always coming back to the same building. 
There is also a weird figure of a girl in white on the road. They find themselves in some kind abandoned psychiatric hospital or institution, where they were treated ( or experimented on ) as kids.
They don't have good memories about it and are slowly being killed one by one. Apparently, this is all a revenge of a classmate girl who was with them and died from torture. The kids who are now adults either didn't protect her or left her, and now her ghost is killing all of them. In the end, only one woman is left alive, slowly figuring out what is going on.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I think this may be the film Crazy Eights with a review and synopsis here - Warning, serious spoilers in the review, but the synopsis pretty much tells it all anyway.

Six friends, including a professor (Dina Meyer) and a priest (George Newbern), gather for the funeral of a childhood pal, who has left behind a will asking them to dig up an old time capsule. They excavate the container and are shocked to find a young girl's skeleton inside. Unnerved, the friends get lost and end up in a long-abandoned government facility where sadistic medical experiments were once performed on children -- and they're now trapped and at the mercy of a vengeful ghost.

